# How to fix Infinite reload on $state.go angularjs1 inside $transitions.onError

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to reload the state after a $transition.error, this is when I press f5 on my keyboard to refresh the child state. I always get a status 302 that's why I am trying to reload the state, if I will get a 200 response.

```
//inside module.run
    $transitions.onError({}, function(transition) {
     console.log("Error Transition from " + transition.from().name
        + " to " + transition.to().name);
        $state.go(transition.to().name); //infinite reload here

    });

//inside app.js
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('sysad', {
            url : '/',
            templateUrl : 'main/main.html',
            controller : 'MainController',
            controllerAs : 'mainCtrl'
        }).state('sysad.manageCaseOutline',
        {
            url : 'manageCaseOutline',
            templateUrl : 'managecaseoutline/managecaseoutline.html',
            controller : 'ManageCaseOutlineController',
            controllerAs : 'mngCaseOtlCtrl'
        })

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```